# Roberts Edge Detector how to use?

Tags: edge-detection, homework

I am trying to use Roberts edge detection to process an image. Do I just apply both of the masks to the image and perform convolution as normal? Could someone give me the breakdown of how to use this edge detection method, as I am trying to program it to process a greyscale image. I convoluted the image using both kernels separately  but the image dent' look right.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Robert's Cross is a little tricky because it's not an odd size (2x2 rather than 3x3 or 5x5). I've done it using numpy+scipy using a padded 3x3 convolution mask.

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
import Image

roberts_cross_v = np.array( [[ 0, 0, 0 ],
                             [ 0, 1, 0 ],
                             [ 0, 0,-1 ]] )

roberts_cross_h = np.array( [[ 0, 0, 0 ],
                             [ 0, 0, 1 ],
                             [ 0,-1, 0 ]] )
def load_image( infilename ) :
    img = Image.open( infilename )
    img.load() 
    # note signed integer
    return np.asarray( img, dtype="int32" )

def save_image( data, outfilename ) :
    img = Image.fromarray( np.asarray( np.clip(data,0,255), dtype="uint8"), "L" )
    img.save( outfilename )

def roberts_cross( infilename, outfilename ) :
    image = load_image( infilename )

    vertical = ndimage.convolve( image, roberts_cross_v )
    horizontal = ndimage.convolve( image, roberts_cross_h )

    output_image = np.sqrt( np.square(horizontal) + np.square(vertical))

    save_image( output_image, outfilename )

infilename = sys.argv[1]
outfilename = sys.argv[2]
roberts_cross( infilename, outfilename )
```

From the Wikipedia entry on Robert's Cross. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roberts_Cross

[image: Image from Robert's Cross Entry on Wikipedia]

My script's output.

[image: My script output]

Comment: Do you square every pixel value in the image?

Comment: Yes. The "np.sqrt( np.square(horizontal) + np.square(vertical))" gives the vector magnitude between the horizontal, vertical directions.

Comment: @DavidPoole Robert's edge detector wiki is fantastic - simple, to the point, and illustrative. How/why is it sensitive to noise VS other gradient measures? Isnt there only one 'true' gradient measure?

Comment: I am trying to implement this function in python (Spyder version) but I am having trouble understanding the arguments it takes and how to feed them? what is infilename and outfilename? Thanks
Sam

Comment: infilename is a grayscale (1 plane) image. outfilename is just an output file the script will write to. The input/output images can be jpeg, png, tif, etc, the Image library (now Pillow) will interpret the image format based on the file extension. Example: python3 rcross.py bicycle.jpg out.tif

Comment: Small fix to run with the new Pillow library:  from PIL import Image  instead of import Image